# Unstructured data, NLP Lemmatize Book Review

Tags: python, nltk, file-writing, file-read, lemmatization

Here I have m trying to read the content let's say 'book1.txt' and here I have to remove all the special characters and punctuation marks and word tokenise the content using nltk's word tokeniser.
Lemmatize those token using  wordnetLemmatizer
And write those token into csv file one by one.
Here is the code I m using which obviously is not working but just need some suggestion on this please.

```
    import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
import csv
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

file_out=open('data.csv','w')
with open('book1.txt','r') as myfile:
  for s in myfile:
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(s)
    words=[word.lower() for word in words if word.isalpha()]
    for word in words:
      token=WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(words,'v')
      filtered_sentence=[""]
      for n in words:
        if n not in token:
          filtered_sentence.append(""+n)
        file_out.writelines(filtered_sentence+["\n"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some issues here, most notably with the last 2 for loops.

The way you are doing it made it write it as follows:

```
word1
word1word2
word1word2word3
word1word2word3word4
........etc
```

I'm guessing that is not the expected output. I'm assuming the expected output is:

```
word1
word2
word3
word4
........etc (without creating duplicates)
```

I applied the code below to a 3 paragraph [Cat Ipsum](http://www.catipsum.com/) file. Note that I changed some variable names due to my own naming conventions.

```py
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('wordnet')
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from pprint import pprint


# read the text into a single string.
with open("book1.txt") as infile:
    text = ' '.join(infile.readlines())
words = word_tokenize(text)
words = [word.lower() for word in words if word.isalpha()]


# create the lemmatized word list
results = []
for word in words:
    # you were using words instead of word below
    token = WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(word, "v")
    # check if token not already in results. 
    if token not in results:
        results.append(token)


# sort results, just because :)
results.sort()

# print and save the results
pprint(results)
print(len(results))
with open("nltk_data.csv", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(results)
```